# Magento 2 have Any Port Forwarding restriction

Tags: magento-2.0, magento-2.1, docker

I don't know this is off-topic or not, But I need to know magento2 have any port forwarding restrictions,

Because, I have setup port concepts in docker to access my container  magento2  to locally connected another system.

This is Docker Container Setup:

```
docker run -it -d --name containerName -h www.myhost.net -v /var/www/html -p 3000:80 --net mynetwork --ip 172.11.0.10 --privileged myimagename
```

> Then, Execute the Container:

```
docker exec -it containerName bin/bash
```

> volume path **/var/www/html** with in the volume path i write one **index.html** file and  access to another locally connected system its working fine.

```
hostmachineip:3000
```

> After I installed magnento2 in my container with in volume(/var/www/html)
>
> Then access magento 2 to another locally connected system thats redirect this magento 2 url but say **Aborted** and show blank page.

```
hostmachineip:3000
```

**Reference:**

[image]

> But: if I call **host machine** its working file,

```
 hostmachineip:3000
```

Its redirect to right server, show magento2 home page.

**remote machine** only not working.

My Configuration Files:

**Loadbalancer** Machine Conf file:

```
    upstream backend {
       ip_hash;
       server 172.11.0.10 weight=5;
       server 172.11.0.20 weight=2;

    }


    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  myhost.net  www.myhost.net;

       location / {

        proxy_pass http://backend;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;

         }

    location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|pdf|html|htm)$ {
        }

     }
```

> include /etc/nginx/proxy_params File:

```
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    client_max_body_size 100M;
    client_body_buffer_size 1m;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 256 16k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
```

> Server 1 Configuration File:  /etc/nginx/site-available/default (server 172.11.0.10)

```
  # nginx + magento2 server configuration 

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:3000;

        server_name www.myhost.net  myhost.net;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error_log;


        root  /var/www/html;

        location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        }

        # Deny access to specific directories no one
        # in particular needs access to anyways.
        location /app/ { deny all; }
        location /includes/ { deny all; }
        location /lib/ { deny all; }
        location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
        location /pkginfo/ { deny all; }
        location /report/config.xml { deny all; }
        location /var/ { deny all; }

        # Allow only those who have a login name and password
        # to view the export folder. Refer to /etc/nginx/htpassword.

        location /var/export/ {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
        autoindex on;
        }

        # Deny all attempts to access hidden files
        # such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, etc...

        location ~ /\. {
         deny all;
         access_log off;
         log_not_found off;
        }

        # This redirect is added so to use Magentos
        # common front handler when handling incoming URLs.

        location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
        }

        # Forward paths such as /js/index.php/x.js
        # to their relevant handler.

        location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
        }

       # pass the PHP scripts to FPM socket

       location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/html;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;

        #send bad requests to 404
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

         include fastcgi_params;
    }
    }
```

**Update 1:**

Now, Port forwarding working based on blow i Posted answer, But view without **css and images.**  But if I call host machine it calling all css and images and working fine.

**Remote machine only doesn't call CSS and Images.**

While I Test Port forwarding in remote machine, get contents form hostmachine, but remote machine **check images and css**  with in  machine not a host machine. That is what this problem occur.

I **tried This Configuration** also: But Still have same problem.

```
  upstream fastcgi_backend {
       server  unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    server {
       listen 80;
       server_name www.myhost.net myhost.net;

       set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html;
       set $MAGE_MODE developer;
       include /var/www/html/nginx.conf.sample;
    }
```

nginx.conf.sample Configuration File:

```
      root $MAGE_ROOT;

        index index.php;
        autoindex off;
        charset off;

        add_header 'X-Content-Type-Options' 'nosniff';
        add_header 'X-XSS-Protection' '1; mode=block';

        location /setup {
            root $MAGE_ROOT;
            location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
                fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
            }

            location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
                allow all;
            }

            location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            }
        }

        location /update {
            root $MAGE_ROOT;
            location ~ ^/update/index.php {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
                include        fastcgi_params;
            }

            # deny everything but index.php
            location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
                allow all;
            }

            location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            }
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location /pub {
            location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
                allow all;
            }
            alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }

        location /static/ {
            if ($MAGE_MODE = "production") {
                expires max;
            }
            location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                expires +1y;

                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
                }
            }
            location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
                add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                expires    off;

                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                   rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
                }
            }
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
            }
           add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }

        location /media/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;

            location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
                allow all;
            }

            location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                expires +1y;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
            }
            location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
                add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                expires    off;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
            }
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }

        location /media/customer/ {
            deny all;
        }

        location /media/downloadable/ {
            deny all;
        }

        location /media/import/ {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ cron\.php {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

            fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
            fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=256M \n max_execution_time=600";
            fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
            fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;

            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
```

**if I install magento 2 with port**

For example:

```
   myhost.com:3000/
```

Now, occur **reverse problem,** remote machine working fine, host-machine **doesn't call  css and images.**

### **Update 2:**

**Do you set the base_url?**

```
  Yes , I set BaseUrl (www.myhost.com)
```

**What Magento version are you using?**

```
    I use Magento Version 2.0.8
```

**Retrun Html page Looks Like:**

[image]

**what the URL to the CSS etc files?**

```
    While port forwarding Css and all other static contents goes to 404 page
```

**reference:**

[image]
 **Are they coming back correct?**

```
 No, while click css path, goes to 404 page.
```

**Can you open the CSS file in a web browser and download them?**

```
    I cannot download css file in a webbrowser.
```

**Reference Info:**

**loadbalancer docker:**

I have create docker with portforwarding using port 3000 and nginx loadbalancer

```
  IP: 172.17.0.2

  docker run -it -d  -h www.myhost.net -v /var/www/html/ --privileged -p 3000:80  --name containername1   remoteserver11
```

**magento machine:**

I have installed nginx + Magento  with portforwarding using port 3001.

```
 IP: 172.17.0.4
 Hostname: www.myhost.net
 magento baseurl:www.myhost.net

    docker run -it -d  -h www.myhost.net -v /var/www/html/ --privileged -p 3001:80  --name containername2   remoteserver11
```

**LoadBalancer Machine Configuration:**

```
    upstream backend {
       ip_hash;
       server 172.17.0.4;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  myhost.net  www.myhost.net;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        }
```

**Magento Machine Configuration:**

```
    upstream fastcgi_backend {
       server  unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    server {
       listen 80;
       server_name www.myhost.net  myhost.net;

       set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html;
       set $MAGE_MODE developer;
       include /var/www/html/nginx.conf.sample;
    }
```

**include /var/www/html/nginx.conf.sample;**

```
               root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

                index index.php;
                autoindex off;
                charset off;

                add_header 'X-Content-Type-Options' 'nosniff';
                add_header 'X-XSS-Protection' '1; mode=block';

                location /setup {
                    root $MAGE_ROOT;
                    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
                        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
                        fastcgi_index  index.php;
                        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        include        fastcgi_params;
                    }

                    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
                        allow all;
                    }

                    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
                        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                    }
                }

                location /update {
                    root $MAGE_ROOT;
                    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
                        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
                        fastcgi_index  index.php;
                        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
                        include        fastcgi_params;
                    }

                    # deny everything but index.php
                    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
                        allow all;
                    }

                    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
                        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                    }
                }

                location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                }

                location /pub {
                    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
                        allow all;
                    }
                    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
                    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                }

                location /static/ {
                    if ($MAGE_MODE = "production") {
                        expires max;
                    }
                    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
                        add_header Cache-Control "public";
                        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                        expires +1y;

                        if (!-f $request_filename) {
                            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
                        }
                    }
                    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
                        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
                        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                        expires    off;

                        if (!-f $request_filename) {
                           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
                    }
                   add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                }

                location /media/ {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;

                    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
                        allow all;
                    }

                    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
                        add_header Cache-Control "public";
                        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                        expires +1y;
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
                    }
                    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
                        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
                        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                        expires    off;
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
                    }
                    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                }

                location /media/customer/ {
                    deny all;
                }

                location /media/downloadable/ {
                    deny all;
                }

                location /media/import/ {
                    deny all;
                }

                location ~ cron\.php {
                    deny all;
                }

                location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

                    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
                    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=256M \n max_execution_time=600";
                    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
                    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
                    fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;

                    fastcgi_index  index.php;
                    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include        fastcgi_params;
                }
```

After Install magento2, I working fine in host machine calling magento base Url

**Port Forwarding Configuration:**

```
   Hostmachine ip: 192.168.1.10
   Remotemachine ip: 192.168.1.12
```

I added Loadbanacer Docker ip to hostmachine /etc/hosts

```
   172.17.0.2   www.myhost.com
```

then, Add host machine ip to remote machine /etc/hosts

```
   192.168.1.10  www.myhost.com
```

After call magento 2 using port forwarding in remote machine from hostmachine

```
     192.168.1.10:3000
```

Its only show **with out** css an all other static content, see the above image.

Why ?

Magento 2 Have Any Port forwarding Restriction?,

Suggest Me How to Change My Configuration to works both machine(with css + images)?

How to get pub static content also from host machine while port forwarding?.

OR Magento 2 need php support for install in hostmachine, So, Remote Machine also need same php Support ?

Comment: Do you set the base_url?  What Magento version are you using? (2.0, 2.1 etc).  There were some bugs fixed in the area of caching host names when no base_url was defined (it would remember the first host name it saw).  I would look at the HTML of the returned page to see what the URL to the CSS etc files are - are they coming back correct? Can you open the CSS file in a web browser and download them?

Comment: @AlanKent  Thanks for you response, I update my question. Please review Update 2 content

Answer (score 1):

I have missed my configuration setup, that is what this problem occur,

> hostmachine ip: 192.168.1.5(hostmachine.com)
>
> loadbalancer docker ip: 172.11.0.30(mymagentohost.com)
>
> remote machine ip 192.168.1.14(remotemachine.com)

Before I added hostmachine ip addr to remote machine

> # vim /etc/hosts
>
> 192.168.1.5  hostmachine.com

Then, Test Now,

Go to the browser type

> 192.168.1.5:3000

Throw Above Error and Not showing magento2 home page.

After I change  Some Configuration in remote machine

host-machine hostname to docker load-balancer  machine hostname assign to host-machine ip.

> # vim /etc/hosts
>
> 192.168.1.5  mymagentohost.com

Now, Go to the browser type

> 192.168.1.5:3000

Check it Its worked for me, show Magento 2 site on my remote machine. **Without CSS.** and **Images**

But, still I don't know magento 2 have any port restriction or Not